# How can I make this loop assign to half of the vector instead of the entire vector?

Tags: c++, loops

For my class, I am making a program that manages a Hotel.  My 'Test' method creates random rooms and random customers.  Once it has does this, it then takes the random customers it created, and checks them into the random rooms it created.

My goal is for the Test to check-in only **HALF** of the rooms with customers. And leave the other half of the rooms empty. And also, I can only have 1 customer per room.

The method compiles, but their are some flaws:

1. The 'Test' fills ALL the rooms with customers (instead of only half of them).
2. The 'Test' will often assign a single room to multiple customers( For example, Room 301 will now belong to 3 different customers instead of just 1)

Can anyone help me figure out how to fill only half of the rooms that are created.
And also help me figure out how to not let a single room be applied to more than 1 customer?  *I am pretty sure that the last FOR loop in the method should be the only thing that I need to adjust.*

```
string Hotel::test(int numRooms, int numCustomers)
{
    string result;
    for(int i=0;i<numRooms;i++) // **********CREATES RANDOM ROOMS
    {
        Room iRoom(randString(8),
                   randInt(0,1000),
                   randInt(0,1000),
                   randInt(0,1000),
                   randInt(0,1000));
        listofrooms.add(iRoom);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numCustomers;i++) // ***********CREATES RANDOM CUSTOMERS
    {
        Customer cus(randString(8),randNumberString(10),randNumberString(16));
        listofcustomers.add(cus);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<numCustomers+numRooms;i++) // **FILLS RANDOM ROOMS WITH RANDOM CUSTOMERS
    {                                        // **I KNOW THIS IS THE ONLY LOOP I NEED TO ADJUST
        checkIn(listofrooms.getRandID(),listofcustomers.getRandID());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What type is `listofrooms`? `listofcustomers`?

Comment: I created 2 classes, ListOfRooms and ListOfCustomers.  listofrooms(lowercase) is of type ListOfRooms and listofcustomers(lowercase) is of type ListOfCustomers.

Comment: Unless we can see the definitions of those types, as well as `checkIn()`, I don't think this question is concretely answerable.

Comment: @ildjarn, actually it is quite comprehensible. He is asking how to do this, so clearly you can tell him how to implement the types and `checkIn` in the best way.

Comment: @Shahbaz : It's also tagged `homework` -- I'm inclined to demonstrate as little as possible, and aide in fixing the _existing_ code. But, of course, that's hard to do when you can't see the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Part 1

You need half the rooms to be filled. Since only 1 guest can be in any room, you need to fill the rooms `numRooms` times. So, you just need to adjust your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRooms/2; i++)
```

#### Part 2

There are many ways to ensure that. **The naive approach** would be to retry in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRooms/2; i++)
{
    int assignedRoom;
    do
    {
        assignedRoom = listofrooms.getRandID();
    } while (isFull(assignedRoom);
    checkIn(assignedRoom, listofcustomers.getRandID());
}
```

Of course, you wouldn't want the same customer in two rooms, so you need to do the same thing with customers also.

Another method could be to take a random room, and if it was full iterate to next rooms (wrapping around to first room if overflow) until you find an empty room.

Another method could be to `random_shuffle` a copy of the rooms and take the first half.

Like I said, whatever you do with the rooms, you need to do with the customers also.

**recommendation**: Perhaps the best distribution is achieved with the last method (the one with `random_shuffle`. Note that the naive approach has a non-deterministic (and possibly bad) performance.

Comment: Seems like it was a double click accidentally :D (I kill one mouse every half a year, this one has come to an end as well..)

Comment: @Shahbaz, used to be, yeah :) But too much work nowadays. Well, enough of the small talk, let's hope Mike can do his homework!

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, the end condition should be `i<numRooms/2` to fill only half of the rooms.

To have only one customer in each room, you have some choices, depending on your constraints. You have to keep track of which rooms you have assigned already.

For example you can remove the assigned rooms from the list - this may not be allowed in most of the times.

Or you can modify the Room class to containt a boolean that you set when it is filled, and you look for another room if it is filled - again, you said you don't want to change anything but the loop.

You may as well create an array of integers, and index the room array (and, with another one, the customer array, if you don't want to assign costumers more than once) with its randomly selected values, again, removing the values that you assigned before.

Another approach, if you don't need a uniform distribution, to have a couner marking how many rooms have to be filled to have half of them assigned, iterate through the rooms, and for each one, decide if you fill it or not. When the remaining number of unprocessed rooms is equal to the number of rooms to be filled in, fill all of them.